# Notifications disabled (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, notifications

My new laptop is running Windows 10. I was running on battery without the power supply plugged in. No notification was received at the default `Power Options > Advanced settings > Battery > Low battery level` of 10%. When the battery level got to the `Critical battery level` of 5%, the laptop hibernated without warning.

After investigating, I found that `Settings > System > Notifications & actions` has notifications turned off and greyed out. A message is displayed about "Some of these settings are hidden or managed by your organisation.". This is a personal (i.e. private) laptop and the user is an Administrator.

[image: Notifications turned off]

Why are notifications turned off? And why does Windows think my "organisation" is managing some settings?

Comment: “Why are notifications turned off?” - “Some of these settings …” is typically displayed for one of two reasons. Your system is connected to an AD domain server and configured through a group policy or you have some other required setting disabled or you configured the option through a local group policy. As you are the Administrator you will have to tell us which one is the case.

Comment: @Ramhound: Group policies have not been touched, at least not directly. I do remember getting several notifications (you get bombarded with them when Windows is first used). I certainly clicked "Do not show XYZ notifications" a few times...but nothing related to the battery. `gpedit.msc` has not been touched.

Comment: Have you used any tools to improve privacy? Many of those tools will disable required options for other features to work without properly explaining the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it turned out that the `Windows Push Notifications System Service` service (WpnService) was set to `Disabled`. After setting that to `Automatic`, checking the following registry settings, then rebooting, battery notifications started appearing.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Use on Windows 10 (may apply to Windows 11) if the "low battery" notification does not work

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications]
"ToastEnabled"=dword:00000001
"NoToastApplicationNotification"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications]
"NoToastApplicationNotification"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer]
"DisableNotificationCenter"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications]
"NoToastApplicationNotification"=dword:00000000
"ToastEnabled"=dword:00000001
```